# How to use back slash in NSURL

Tags: iphone

I am trying to call a web service on iPhone as follows;

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://DOMAIN\Username:Password@IPAddress/ServiceName"];
```

When this line is executed url is **nil**. But when i remove **"\"** from above call, url contains the value.

I have already tried using "\\" but it didn't worked. Here is my code

```
NSString *Domain = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DOMAIN"]; 
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserName"]; 
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@\\%@:password@IPAddress",Domain,name]; 

//Above lines executes properly and contains the following 
"https://DOMAIN\UserName:password@IPAddress"
```

But when the following line gets executed url is nil

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Can any body help me how i can put "\" in URL?

Thanks.
Yasar

Answer (score 3):

Put another \ in front of it to escape it:

```
http://DOMAIN\\Username
```

Comment: Simple as that. The backslash is used as a special input character in many languages, e.g `\n` means new line.

Comment: I have already tried this. And URL becomes nil. Kindly suggest

Answer (score 1):

Use an UTF8 encoding for the String.

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```